# How to parse JSON in golang without unmarshaling twice

Tags: json, go

I've got a web socket connection that sends different types of messages in a JSON object, and I want to unmarshal the contents into some known structs. 
To do this, I figure I should do the following:

Step 1) Unmarshal the JSON into a generic map[string]interface{}

Step 2) Find the key I'm looking for

Step 3) Try to cast the value into one of my types (this fails)

Step 3 alternate) json marshal this value and unmarshal it to my known struct

If I try to use `myStruct, ok := value.(myType)` it will fail, but if I json.marshal(value) and then json.unmarshal to myStruct, it works just fine. Is that how I'm supposed to do this? Going json-> map[string]interface{} -> json -> myStruct seems redundant to me.

Sample code:

https://play.golang.org/p/to_0Id_ja9

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Ping struct {
    Ping string `json:"ping"`
}

type Ack struct {
    Messages []Message `json:"messages"`
}

type Message string

func main() {
    testJSON := []byte(`{"ack":{"messages":["Hi there","Hi again"]}}`)
    var myAck = Ack{}
    var myMap map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(testJSON, &myMap)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error unmarshalling: ", err)
    }
    for k, v := range myMap {
        fmt.Printf("key: %s, value: %s \n", k, v)

        switch k {
        case "ping":
            fmt.Println(k, " is a ping", v)
        case "ack":
            fmt.Println(k, " is an ack containing a message list")
            ackjson, err := json.Marshal(v)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("marshal error: ", err)
            }
            err = json.Unmarshal(ackjson, &myAck)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("unmarshal error", err)
            } else {
                fmt.Println("New ack object: ", myAck)
            }
        default:
            fmt.Printf("%s is of a type (%T) I don't know how to handle", k, v)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

One solution is to partially unmarshal the data by unmarshalling the values into a [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) instead of an `interface{}`

```
var myMap map[string]json.RawMessage
```

Later in the switch, which still is required, you do not need to marshal. Just do:

```
err = json.Unmarshal(v, &myAck)
```

**Playground:** https://play.golang.org/p/NHd3uH5e7z

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a struct which contains all keys you *might* receive, then unmarshal once, finally based on which keys are `nil` you can decide what kind of packet you got.

The example below displays this behavior: https://play.golang.org/p/aFG6M0SPJs

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "strings"
)


type Ack struct {
  Messages []string `json:"messages"`
}

type Packet struct {
  Ack  * Ack    `json:"ack"`
  Ping * string `json:"ping"`
}

func runTest(testJSON []byte) {
  var p = Packet{}
  err := json.Unmarshal(testJSON, &p)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error unmarshalling: ", err)
  }
  if (p.Ack != nil) {
    fmt.Println("Got ACK: ", strings.Join(p.Ack.Messages, ", "));
  } else if (p.Ping != nil){
          fmt.Println("Got PING");
  }
}

func main() {
  tests := [][]byte{
    []byte(`{"ack":{"messages":["Hi there","Hi again"]}}`),
    []byte(`{"ping": "Are you there?"}`),
  }
  for _, test := range tests {
    runTest(test)
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you!
Any reason that you use Ack * Ack? How is that different from just Ack Ack?

Comment: if it's not a pointer, then it can't be `nil`, you can still check if it's empty, but it's easier to check that it's `nil`

Comment: dear downvoters, please explain, is there something wrong with this answer?

Comment: @Mobius gave you an upvote, this is similar to what I did for a project. Pointers allowed you to see if that data was provided or not, which makes it quick to validate.  The parse the json twice crowd may not realize at how slow that can be sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a common key between all messages (eg: `type`) which indicates what type of message it is. After this, if the messages aren't sufficiently complicated, you can build the raw structs from the other map keys / type assert map values:

From some related websocket code I wrote that does this:
https://github.com/blaskovicz/cut-me-some-slack/blob/master/chat/message.go#L66

```
func DecodeClientMessage(c *ClientMessage) (typedMessage interface{}, err error) {
    buff := map[string]string{}
    err = json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(c.Raw)).Decode(&buff)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    switch t := buff["type"]; t {
    case "message":
        channelID := buff["channel_id"]
        if channelID == "" {
            err = fmt.Errorf("invalid client message received: missing channel_id")
            return
        }
        cms := &ClientMessageSend{ChannelID: channelID, Text: buff["text"]}
        if cms.Text == "" {
            err = fmt.Errorf("invalid client message received: missing text")
        } else {
            typedMessage = cms
        }
```

... and then the caller code does a `result.(type)` assertion and switch:
https://github.com/blaskovicz/cut-me-some-slack/blob/master/chat/hub.go#L150

```
switch m := raw.(type) {
case *ClientMessageHistory:
    channelID := h.resolveSlackChannel(m.ChannelID)
    if channelID == "" {
        log.Printf("error: no channel found matching %s\n", m.ChannelID)
        return
    }
    var username string
    if c.Client.User != nil {
        username = c.Client.User.Username
    } else {
        username = "<anonymous>"
    }
    log.Printf("sending previous messages for channel %s to client %s\n", channelID, username)
    for _, prevMessage := range h.previousMessages(channelID, m.Limit) {
        c.Client.send <- prevMessage
    }
```